# Dynamic Control Template in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to make a button in Silverlight use a control template to change the way it looks.

I need to do this dynamically in code (not xaml markup).
The Button object has a Template property to which you can assign a ControlTemplate.

But how do you stuff UI elements into the ControlTemplate?
(In WPF, there is a VisualTree property but no such property exists in Silverlight)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but just in case.  To create buttons using a control template in code behind (not XAML) I've done it like this:

1. load the control template from an xml definition (below is a link to the source)

   ```
       byte[] bytes = ReadBytesFromStream("BestBuyRemix.BL.buttontemplate.xml");
       string buttonTemplate = "";
       UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
       buttonTemplate = encoding.GetString(bytes.ToArray(), 0, (int)bytes.Length);
   ```
2. create the button and add it to the visual tree (in this case a wrap panel)

string onebutton = string.Format(buttonTemplate, mnu.CatItemName, mnu.CatItemImage,
                             "{StaticResource buttonStyle1}",
                            "{StaticResource CatItemNameBlock}", "{StaticResource ThumbNailPreview}",
                             ictr.ToString());
            ictr += 1;

```
        Button bt = (Button)XamlReader.Load(onebutton);
        bt.Tag = mnu.CatItemPageUri;
        bt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(bt_Click);

        Wrappable.Children.Add(bt);
```

I wrote a post on my blog about the Best Buy Remix API which uses this to build a product list in the details page.  It has a link to the Silverlight source. In case you're interested.
[blog post link](http://www.faxt.com/blog/post/2009/01/ReMix2c-a-new-API-from-Best-Buy.aspx)